# Unable to find an array element when it should be there

Tags: perl

I am receiving output from some process as this and i want to search particular element from the out put of that process using perl I have done as below but still it return FALSE even if there is element.I think something i am doing wrong in parsing help any pointers .
Thanks

Output from process:

```
origin-server-pool-1
http_TestABC
https_TestABC
```

Script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @result_listosp; #assigned from output process given above


my $osp="http_TestABC";
my $status_osp_check= check_if_entity_exists($osp,@result_listosp);
print $status_osp_check;


sub check_if_entity_exists() 
{
    my $entity = shift;
    my @entityarray = @_;


    my $status="FALSE";

    if ( grep { $_ eq $entity} @entityarray) {
        $status="TRUE";
        return $status;
    } 
    else {
        return $status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are using backticks (`qx()`).

This is like assigning:

```
@result_listosp = ( "origin-server-pool-1\n",    # Note the
                            "http_TestABC\n",    # trailing
                           "https_TestABC\n" );  # newlines
```

The reason why the `grep` is failing is because `"http_TestABC" eq "http_TestABC\n"` is false.

Two ways to fix this:

- `chomp @result_listosp;` to eliminate the newline endings
- Use a regex match (`=~`) instead of an exact match (`eq`)